# mplayer freezes while attempting to play a file via the python subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

Here's a simple script just to illustrate the problem. The script is supposed to play any video and audio file that can be played with mplayer.

```
import sys
import time
import subprocess


def get_sound_duration(file_to_play):
    ffprobe = ["ffprobe", "-v", "error", 
               "-show_entries", "format=duration", "-of", 
               "default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1", file_to_play]
    duration = subprocess.Popen(ffprobe,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return duration.stdout.readlines()[0].strip()


def play(player=sys.argv[1], file_to_play=sys.argv[2]):
    proc = subprocess.Popen([player, file_to_play],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        time.sleep(float(get_sound_duration(file_to_play)))
        proc.terminate()
        proc.wait()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    play()
```

The problem with it is that when I run it with mplayer as follows:

```
$ python play.py mplayer PATH_TO_FILE
```

it hangs in less than a minute. Out of all players that I tested this script with, this issue only occurred with mplayer and mpv (which is based on mplayer, so, roughly speaking, it's the same). 
I've found a way to fix it, but I'm not really satisfied with the fix. To fix it I just have to take the stderr parameter out of the `Popen` constructor in the `play` function. But however I don't understand how it solves the problem.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Possibly relevant: from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr): "Warning: Use `communicate()` rather than `.stdin.write`, `.stdout.read` or `.stderr.read` to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process."

Comment: @glibdud Okay, gimme a sec to check it out.

Comment: @glibdud So I've replaced `duration.stdout.readlines()[0].strip()` with `duration.communicate()[0].strip()` but the issue persisted...